# Sum different range of values in single column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet which produces costings for products, in column I the product totals are grouped, image attached.

[image]

Instead of having individual totals i would like a total for each grouped amount, I would like the outcome of column I to look like column K in the image. The amounts aren't always in the same cells and can vary from 1 product to several. I would like to do this with VBA as i already have code written for other parts of the process.
Any help would be appreciated.

Below is my code that creates the values in column I

```
 On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  FirstRow = Columns(2).Find(What:="NO", Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row
  LastRow = Columns(2).Find(What:="NO", Lookat:=xlWhole, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row

  Dim r As Range

  With ActiveSheet

  For Each r In .Range("G" & FirstRow & ":" & "G" & LastRow)
        If r.Value <> "" Then
            r.Offset(0, 2).Value = (r.Value * 15.5) / 1000
        End If
        Next r
  End With


ErrorHandler:
  FirstRow = 0
  LastRow = 0
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the code that produces column I.

Comment: Are they formulas in column I? You could do this using `SpecialCells` and loop through the areas in I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that [Scott Craner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4851590/scott-craner) has answered a similar question somewhere with a better excel formula.

Meanwhile, If data is not too huge to make calculations slow then try following in cell K2 and copy it down.

`=IF(AND(ISBLANK(I3)=TRUE,ISBLANK(I2)=FALSE),SUM(INDIRECT("I"&LOOKUP(2,1/ISBLANK($I$1:I2),ROW($I$1:I2))&":I"&ROW())),"")`

[image]

So, if you want to replace the column I based on column G then formula in I2 will be

`=IF(AND(ISBLANK(G3)=TRUE,ISBLANK(G2)=FALSE),SUM(INDIRECT("G"&LOOKUP(2,1/ISBLANK($G$1:G2),ROW($G$1:G2))&":G"&ROW()))*15.5/1000,"")`

in VBA

```
With ActiveSheet

For Each r In .Range("G" & FirstRow & ":" & "G" & LastRow)
    If r.Value <> "" Then
    With r.Offset(0, 2)
        .FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(AND(ISBLANK(R[1]C[-2])=TRUE,ISBLANK(RC[-2])=FALSE),SUM(INDIRECT(""G""&LOOKUP(2,1/ISBLANK(R1C7:RC[-2]),ROW(R1C7:RC[-2]))&"":G""&ROW()))*15.5/1000,"""")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    End If
Next r
End With
```

Comment: Top Man. It works perfectly, Thank You so much Naresh.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)